# which way is appropriate to check table existence

Tags: sql, database, performance, oracle, oracle11g

I want check a particular table existence in Oracle, which way is more general and appropriate, I have 2 ways listed below, the way 1 run fast if table existing, because it just run one sql

1. Handle the exception and get know it.

   ```
   create or replace procedure get_id_only (id out number) as
   begin
   execute immediate 'SELECT id FROM TABLE_NAME where rownum = 1' into id;
   exception    
       when others then
         if (sqlcode = -942) then
           SELECT id into id FROM my_another_table;
         else 
           raise;
         end if;
   end;
   ```
2. Check user table to see if it is existing.

   ```
   create or replace procedure get_id_only (id out number) as
    count number;
   begin
     SELECT count(*) into count FROM user_tables 
          WHERE table_name = 'TABLE_NAME';
     if (count = 0) then
       SELECT id into id FROM my_another_table;
       return;
     end if;

     execute immediate 'SELECT id FROM TABLE_NAME where rownum = 1' into id;

   end;
   ```

Comment: I'd recommend method #2.

Comment: can you given a reason? it hits user_tables every times, so it have extra costs.

Comment: Why do you need to check for the existence of a table?  This is an unusual requirement for a stored procedure.  It might be a sign that there's a different problem that needs to be solved first.

Comment: I Agree with Egor.  As a general coding rule one should always anticipate exceptions, and not rely on them for program control.

Comment: The two methods you propose in your question are not functionally equivalent.  For example, they might return different results if there's a view or synonym named `TABLE_NAME` or if `CURRENT_SCHEMA` has been set to something other than the definer's schema.

Comment: what's meaning for "CURRENT_SCHEMA has been set to something other than the definer's schema.", for the current user who got a connection from oracle, he should have no two tables with same name

Comment: Views or synonym could lead to different results, but my previous statement regarding `CURRENT_SCHEMA` is incorrect.  `CURRENT SCHEMA` is a session parameter that can be set to specify the schema qualifier to use when the qualifier is omitted.  See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/general009.htm#ADMIN02101) for an example.  However, the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00809) also points out that `CURRENT_SCHEMA` is effectively set to the owner for the duration of the procedure call.

Answer (score 1):

As you said the first one is the best and most efficient way. Because catching the "table not found" exception: this avoids the overhead of checking if the table exists twice;

Comment: I disagree - using the exception handler as a 'goto' is not considered good practice.